# What will happen if the prime mover driving synchronous machine is accidentally disconnected?

Tags: motor, power-engineering, alternator, power-grid, synchronous-motor

What happens to a synchronous machine connected to an infinite grid, acting as a generator, when its prime mover fails i.e. when mechanical input at the shaft reduces to 0?

I'm assuming that the protective equipments which should've tripped unit in this case failed to do so.

EDIT:
I thought that electromagnetic torque would not change when prime mover torque goes 0, which were wrong as I realised after disccusion in comments.

I found [answer on some another Q&A site to similar question](https://www.quora.com/What-will-happen-when-the-prime-mover-is-removed-from-the-synchronous-generator-at-the-time-of-running) which confused me. I'd like to quote a few points from there here:

> Here are the various possibilities for a synchronous generator connected to grid when Prime mover is accidently decoupled. The mode depends on whether the field winding is excited.
>
> 1. Field Excitation is available ( Field ON) : Machine will work as a         Synchronous Motor rotating in the same direction.
> 2. Field Excitation is failed ( Field OFF)
>
> Cylindrical rotor machine : work as Induction Motor running in same direction with speed less than synchronous speed.
>
> Salient pole machine : work as Reluctance Motor running in same direction at synchronous speed.

I now understand point 1 (field = on case), but I don't completely understand filed = off case.

It appears that motor operating as induction motor case is written considering that damper windings and even field windings will produce induction motor torque.

Question 1 : Is it theoretically sound reasoning if we consider that field winding won't burn and grid is infinite?

Question 2  : Practically it would burn field winding right? And will also cause violent changes at bus to which it is connected?

As far as reluctance motor case is concerned, I believe it is written owing to small reluctance torque which is present in synchronous machines and is independent of excitation. Based on [this EE.SE question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/293582/64230), I am concluding that it can run at synchronous speed due to this small reluctance torque provided it overcomes load torque on its shaft due to friction and windage. It is stated over there that is very unlikely however since reluctance torque would be very low.

Question 3 : But even if reluctance torque was capable of overcoming air friction, how likely it is that machine after this violent fluctuations would remain in synchronism? In fact I would like to ask the same question for first case where it runs as synchronous motor also. Isn't it more likely that following violent oscillations motor would be pulled out of synchronism? Just because 'it can' stay in synch, doesn't means it would, right?

Comment: Can you justify why you think "As there's no prime mover torque, electromagnetic torque will aggressively retard the rotor.". I don't think this is the case. I.e. the Quora answer pt. 1 is correct.

Comment: @anrieff Before prime mover failed, prime mover torque would be equal to electromagnetic torque, when we remove prime mover, there would be no prime mover torque, but electromagnetic torque would remain same.... wait wait it won't.... oh yess... I see where I failed.... are his other points correct too?

Comment: for the "Field=OFF" case I don't know enough to give a confident answer. The Field=ON case is correct AFAIK.

Comment: Ok thank you for your answer.